# JMeter Network distribution in load testing

Tags: jmeter

How can i distribute networks while load testing in JMeter?

Suppose my load test is of 1 hr. and i have 100 users. I want to distribute network like-
              20% users - 2G speed
              40% users - 3G speed
              rest      - 4G speed.

OR, other scenario like throughout the whole test of 1hr. 20% traffic will on 2G speed, 40% traffic on 3G and rest on 4G speed.

Can anyone tell me that how to mimic this network behavior in JMeter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You will need to kick off 3 JMeter instances in [Distributed Mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)
2. For 1st JMeter instance add the next lines to *user.properties* file to mimic [2G network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2G):

   ```
   httpclient.socket.http.cps=6400
   httpclient.socket.https.cps=6400
   ```
3. For 2nd JMeter instance add the next lines to *user.properties* file to mimic [3G network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3G)

   ```
   httpclient.socket.http.cps=2688000
   httpclient.socket.https.cps=2688000
   ```
4. For 3rd JMeter instance add the next lines to *user.properties* file to mimic [4G network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4G):

   ```
   httpclient.socket.http.cps=19200000
   httpclient.socket.https.cps=19200000
   ```

More information: [How to Simulate Different Network Speeds in Your JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-simulate-different-network-speeds-your-jmeter-load-test)

Comment: Thank you for replying.

One more thing that I want to know - is it not possible to mimic different network speed with single JMeter instance? Because other load testing tool like Visual Studio provide option for network distribution while creating load test with single instance only.

Can we do like that.

Comment: As of now - it is not possible